# warning C6031 return value ignored in macro expansion

Tags: c++, error-handling, macros, compiler-warnings

I'm using following code to format `HRESULT` to message and write the message to file only if `HRESULT` is an error.

The code compiles and works fine, except that I'm getting following [compiler warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6031?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C6031)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=vs-2019):

> Warning   C6031   Return value ignored: 'wcsrchr'.

I don't want to disable warning but to resolve it, but I'm not able to figure out how?
Here is a minimum compilable code:

```
// compile with: /Wall
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cwchar>       // std::wcsrchr
#include <comdef.h>     // _com_error
#include <iostream>     // std::cin

// Show only file name instead of full path wide version
#define __FILENAME__ (std::wcsrchr(TEXT(__FILE__), L'\\') ? std::wcsrchr(TEXT(__FILE__), L'\\') + 1 : TEXT(__FILE__))

// Writes a sprintf-formatted string to the logging file.
#define TRACE(...) DebugLogTrace(__VA_ARGS__)

// Log HRESULTs if failed.
#define LOG_IF_FAILED(file_name, line, hr) if constexpr (FAILED(hr)) \
    { TRACE((TEXT("%s %i %s"), file_name, line, _com_error(hr).ErrorMessage())); }

// Writes a sprintf-formatted string to the logging file.
void DebugLogTrace(PCTSTR format_string, ...) noexcept
{
    // implementation not important
}

int main()
{
      // generate example failure
      LOG_IF_FAILED(__FILENAME__, __LINE__, E_FAIL);

      std::cin.get();
      return 0;
}
```

Example file output for `E_FAIL` error code:

> 7:50:11  Unspecified error

Comment: Explicitly cast to `void`?

Comment: Nitpcik: `__FILENAME__` [is a reserved identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). You are tangoing with undefined behavior by defining it.

Comment: @L.F. `LOG_IF_FAILED((void)__FILENAME__, __LINE__, E_FAIL);` results in `C4548` I see now what is the problem! I should reimplement my LOG_IF_FAILED macro because output is wrong, it excludes filename :)

Comment: @Nitpcik thanks for link I'll rename my macros...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the warning to go away by changing:

```
#define LOG_IF_FAILED(file_name, line, hr) if constexpr (FAILED(hr)) \
    { TRACE((TEXT("%s %i %s"), file_name, line, _com_error(hr).ErrorMessage())); }
```

to

```
#define LOG_IF_FAILED(file_name, line, hr) if constexpr (FAILED(hr)) \
    { TRACE(TEXT("%s %i %s"), file_name, line, _com_error(hr).ErrorMessage()); }
```

That is: `{ TRACE((..., ..., ..., ...)); }` to `{ TRACE(..., ..., ..., ...); }`

But I have to admit, that I don't know if there are some other unintended result of removing the extra parenthesis.

Comment: Yes that did the trick! file output now prints entry string, thanks a lot!